# How to stack two inline images when view is smaller?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have two inline images stack as the window size gets smaller. However, I've tried several things with no luck. What's the best way to accomplish this? Here's my code that I'm working with:

```
<div class="coming">
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="appstore.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="googleplay.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.coming {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.logos {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}
```

This is what they look like in a normal window, but I want them to stack on top of one another when smaller.

Comment: Unless your're talking about a _specific_ viewport size you'd like this to happen at, your example all ready has the behavior you describe.

Comment: Thanks guys. I liked into media queries and will take that into consideration now in the future. @vanburen - I figured out from your comment that nothing had to change besides adding container-fluid to the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it by doing this:

```
<div class="coming">
    <div class="apple_logo container-fluid">
        <img src="appstore.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="apple_logo container-fluid">
        <img src="googleplay.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

So I just added `'container-fluid'` to each div class.

Comment: You may want to give example of what `container-fluid` does, if you're using a framework also state that outside of using tags, to give other users who find this question better clarity.